# Sentinel nodes in a 2-3 tree

Tags: c#, trees

I want to implement a 2-3 tree in C# language, where every leaf has a unique key. The keys are from a given class that implements the IComparable interface (the specific class is unknown, and it's should work for every class which implements the interface).

I want to use two sentinel nodes to represent plus and minus infinity, but I can't figure out the best way to do it, that won't be too complex.

I thought about creating a class which will implement the IComparable interface, and use it as two leaves in the tree, but I am not sure if that's the best thing to do or not.

Comment: Try it, and see how well it works.

Comment: I think it will work, but I am not sure if it's a good design or not

Comment: Define "good design."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Efficient (with respect to both running time and coding time) and loyal to programming standards like OOP

Comment: Efficiency is going to depend mostly on the shape of the tree, unless you have profoundly inefficient comparison algorithms.  You can measure "loyal to programming standards like OOP" by evaluating your code against those standards.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am not sure if if loyal to OOP standards, for example: In order to compare two keys I must check if one of then is the sentinel, because I can't compare them directly trough the CompareTo method, since the other classes that implements the interface might cast the object, and the program will crash.

Comment: Keep in mind that optimizing for running time might be very different than optimizing for readability. Using many small objects may cause significant memory overhead and cache misses.